# nested forfiles: path and extension filter

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, cmd

is there any possibility to nest two `forfile` commands so that I can filter by **pathname** and by **extension** and then run a command only on those double filtered files?

By example I'd like to get all Outlook HTML-signatures of all users. I can do this by

```
forfiles /s /p c:\Users /m *Signatures* /c "cmd /c forfiles /s /p @path /m *.htm"
```

But this will only display the filenames because it's the default behavior of `forfiles` to call `cmd /c echo @file`.

Changing this doesn't work because then I'd need to set the `/c`-option in the inner `forfiles` command which requires to set the command in quotes resulting in double quotes:

```
forfiles /s /p c:\Users /m *Signatures* /c "cmd /c forfiles /s /p @path /m *.htm /c "cmd /c echo @path""
```

How can I escape the inner quotes or use some different approach to run any command on all files filtered by a substring of path and the file extension?

Kind regards
sc911

[edit] forgot `/s` for recursive searching [/edit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FORFILES` seems to be able to recognise `\"` as the way of escaping inner `"`. So, the following should work:

```
forfiles /p c:\Users /m *Signatures* /c "cmd /c forfiles /p @path /m *.htm /c \"cmd /c echo @path\""
```

Comment: I thought I tried them all, those little, nasty escape chars... Thx a lot!

Answer (score 7):

Instead of `forfiles` you can use two nested `FOR` commands.

see the following one-liner example to test in a cmd prompt

```
@for /d %d in (c:\Users\*signature*) do @for %f in (%d\*.htm) do @echo %f
```

and use this code as a skeleton to include in a BAT file

```
for /d %%d in (c:\Users\*signatures*) do (
  for %%f in (%%d\*.htm) do (
    echo %%f
  )
)
```

Comment: Thx, this will do the trick too, but i'd like to stick on forfiles

Comment: @sc911, this solution will process your files much faster than using `FORFILES` with `CMD.exe`.